# Make NSTextField work like a selectable directory path

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a string that represent a directory path, example "Home/Level1/Level2/Level3/Level4/Level5"
i wish that if user pass the mouse over or click in, per example "Level3" i can recognize what substring he choose and highlight it or call a function.

Comment: Like `NSPathControl`?

Comment: @Willeke Its exactly what im searching, thanks for showing the right direction.